# RavenDB Lucene Query equivalent of Linq Contains

Tags: linq, ravendb, lucene.net, contains

Does anyone know how to write RavenDB Lucene query which is equivalent to the following Linq statement?

var results = events.Where(e => e.Detail.Contains("test"));

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is what you're looking for, but this is using ravendb (build 3548) DocumentQuery wich takes a lucene query in the where statement:

```
using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var result = session.Advanced
        .DocumentQuery<Events>()
        .Where("Details: *test*")
        .ToList();
}
```

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.0/csharp/client-api/querying/query-and-lucene-query

Edit: This might not be very effective in terms of performance. Not sure how lucene is handling these kind of wildcards.